# MySQL Password Not Working

Tags: mysql, passwords

EDIT: I had MySQL installed twice on my machine (XAMPP & on its own)

When I enter my password into MySQL Command Line Client, it rejects my password, gives 1 beep and closes the window. Can anyone provide me with a basic troubleshooting list of steps (from simple to progressively more technical) to regain entry into MySQL once and for all. Also, can anyone tell me what can cause my password to suddenly be rejected? I am also running XAMPP and the MySQL service is both installed and running. Thanks in advance.

I remember when I first got this problem some months ago, if I recall correctly, I solved it by starting the MySQL service from Windows XP's Administrative Tool (something I did stopped the MySQL service and to this day I don't know what it was).

Now the problem has started back again but this time, when I checked Services, the MySQL service was already 'started'.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to access from the local server or over the network?

Comment: Thanks for your reply James. I'm trying to access on my local machine.

Comment: Something is really wrong now. Everytime I try to uninstall the MySQL service from XAMPP by removing the tick from the checkbox, the tick keeps coming back. Furthermore, when I try to stop the MySQL service from XP's administrative tools, it just say MySQL status is "starting" and when I click on it, the MySQL properties dialog box says "startup type: disabled"

Comment: Ive restarted my computer several times, and tried to get MySQL running through both XAMPP and Windows Administrative tools, but the status for MySQL remains as "starting".... This is frustrating!

Comment: Administrative Tools Services keep giving me the message that "the specified service (MySQL) has been marked for deletion". Everytime I try to deselect the checkbox from ZAMPP's control panel, it keeps selecting it back. Awww!

Comment: In Windows taskmanager I am seeing 2 processes named "mysqld.exe". Why?

Comment: After stopping both mysqld.exe programs in Windows taskmanager, I get these 2 messages:
Configuration Manager: A required entry in the registry is missing or an attempt to write to the registry failed.

Unable to open service MySQL for reading on Local Computer. Error 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Now what should I do?

Comment: Ok I reinstalled MySQL as a service by typing in the following in Windows command window: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld --install

MySQL still does not allow me access with my password

Comment: if you can't uninstall/re-install then try starting the service with the --skip-grant-tables option (check documentation for exact syntax) this will allow you to get in without password at which point you can reset the root account password.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out why my password was not working. I had two versions of MySQL installed on my machine (XAMPP and MySQL 5.1). So I deleted the MySQL 5.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

For me (and my similar problem),

```
--password = mypass
```

didn't work, but

```
--password="mypass"
```

did.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the password for the root account? If so, try this from the command line?

```
mysql --user=root --password=your password here
```

or

```
mysql --user=root --password=your password here --database=MySQL
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply James.

If I recall correctly, my password is the root pass.

Ok, the first thing MySQL Command Line Client propts me for is the password doing the above did not work.

So I tried Window command line, I tried the above mentioned commands  at both my root directory (C drive) and inside the MySQL folder. The error message I got was 'root' is not recognized as an internal or external command.... 
Im I doing something wrong when inputing these commands?

Answer (score 2):

Is there an error message when it rejects your password? I wonder if perhaps you are using an outdated client and running into this issue: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/old-client.html

Comment: I think the problem was I had MySQL installed twice on my machine (once in XAMPP & on its own)

Comment: You might want to update your answer. It's a bad link here!

Answer (score 2):

If you set mySQL to **not** begin running on startup, then you need to start it prior to attempting to login. This can be done via the command line, via the task manager if you configured it as a windows service, etc.

For example, here is an explanation of starting the service using cmd

[Starting MySQL from the Windows Command Line | MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-command-line.html)

Answer (score 1):

[How to Reset the Root Password | MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//resetting-permissions.html)

This is the services solution that was mentioned. Use this if you can't remember your root password.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late but - If you have numeric characters in your password and are using the numpad on your keyboard, ensure that the numlock is ON. For some weird reason if you have numlock off MySQL will still interpret a keystroke. This wasn't very obvious to me since my laptop doesn't have a num lock indicator light, thats HP for yah :)

Answer (score 0):

My password suddenly worked again, so I took the following steps to change it:

1. Using Windows Command Prompt, navigate to MySQL's bin directory
2. Type: `mysqladmin -uroot -p password yourNewPassword`
3. Press Enter. You will be prompted for your password, enter it
4. If no error messages/beeps happen, your password was successfully changed
5. Log in using MySQL Command Prompt with your new password

What I don't understand is that WHY all of a sudden my password started back to work after approximately 24 hours? I wish I know so I can avoid this in the future.

Comment: You likely restarted the mysql service (perhaps through restarting your computer). See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another successful solution to this problem.  I reran the installer (the msi), chose the repair option and everything was fixed.